# Angular Image Gallery that dynamically shows the content in a folder

Tags: angular, image-gallery

I am looking for an Angular (not AngularJS) library that allows the display of all images in a given folder as an image gallery *without* the need to specify `src` to each image.

[PHP script that shows the images in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806969/php-script-that-shows-the-images-in-a-folder) does a very similar thing to what I want to achieve, but obviously it is written in PHP script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that entirely in Angular because Angular is a client-side framework, and presumably the images are on the server.

So, you'd have to write a server-side API that provides the list of image URLs to the Angular application.

Then, in Angular, you would probably want to use *ngFor in a component template to loop over the URLs and output HTML "img" tags.

Comment: Thanks, though perhaps it can made possible by combining Angular with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480550/how-to-load-all-the-images-from-one-of-my-folder-into-my-web-page-using-jquery ?